# ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest

I have issue an with gradle build in Android Studio . When I add Admob Activity in the project, while adding the dependencies to the project it throws Two errors

1. `ERROR: Manifest merger failed`
2. org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures
   For 1st issue , it suggests like "  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-32:19 to override.
   "

Even after adding tools: `replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to Androidmanifest gradle sync fails

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ani.admobcheck">

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Ads"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ads"></activity>
    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"


    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiM    ode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



    Build.gralde :
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.ani.admobcheck"

        minSdkVersion 15

        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner      

"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-    

optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I got Sync error as :

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute            
application@appComponentFactory value=   
(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from     
[com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0]   
AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=  
(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to 
<application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-32:19 to override.
```

I tried adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution by adding `googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"` to `app/build.gradle`, since *Google Services* has been updated :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. Added two lines in `gradle.properties` file:

`android.useAndroidX=true`

`android.enableJetifier=true`

These two lines automatically resolved my dependency conflicts between google's files and third party dependencies.